# Beautiful Soup Grabbing next element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to pull the election electoral votes to check when it updates. But the hard part is that all the classes change on every refresh. I want to search for the text `Trump` and then find the next element which is the count.

I can find the element, by searching for the string `Trump`:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=who+is+winning+the+presidential+election&eob=enn/p//1/0///////////"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
elm = soup.find(text='Trump')
print elm.text
```

I found the Trump element, with `lm = soup.find(text='Trump')`, but I don't know how to grab the next element after that one.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is looking for an exact match of a node with that text. Try this:

```
soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('Trump'))
> ["Donald Trump is US president-elect in 'America's Brexit' as Hillary Clinton concedes election - live", 'Donald Trump ', 'Donald Trump wins presidential election, plunging US into uncertain future'... ]
```

You'll instead be looking for a regular expression containing the target text. You can refine the regular expression you're looking for, for example:

```
b.body.findAll(text=re.compile('Trump wins .+? uncertain future'))
> ['Donald Trump wins presidential election, plunging US into uncertain future']
```

Comment: I want to grab the next element. I already grabbed the Trump element, I just want to grab the next one over.

Comment: I think you're looking for `.next_sibling` or `.next_element`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-back-and-forth

Comment: That worked (tested on another site since the google urls change), can you change your answer to that so I can accept?